# Import CSV Line Break Woes

Tags: mysql, bash, csv

I'm using a BASH script to run a LOAD DATA INFILE to MySQL.  My issue is trying to terminate a line correctly. After running my script I notice every other line is skipped. Here's some example data:

CSV File Reads:

```
"COMP","POL","STATUS","TYPE","CODE","MODE","NUMBER"
"220","1243918,"TGI","NA","AS-T5","M6","793930""
"220","1653912,"TGS","NA","NON","M6","793975""
"220","1471618,"TGS","NA","AS-T6","M6","793915""
```

Here's my BASH SCRIPT to Import CSV FILE:

```
mysql -u$User -p$Pass -D$Db<<EOFMYSQL
LOAD DATA INFILE '$InputFile' INTO TABLE $Table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(comp,pol,status,type,code,mode,number);
EOFMYSQL
```

But here's what my rows looks like in my database:

```
220  1243918  TGI  NA  AS-T5  M6 793930""220
220  1471618  TGS  NA  AS-T6  M6 793915""220
```

Notice the last field NUMBER in the database has two sets of quotes and the first field of the next row in the CSV file. The 2nd row is skipped.

I have tried many different LINES TERMINATED BY options but just can't figure out how to designate the line break correctly?!

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Basher

Comment: I must add this is a Windows CSV file, if I remove the ENCLOSED BY '"', my rows are correct but every value in the database has quotations around them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if your file has weird Windowsy carriage returns in it by running:

```
cat -vet yourfile
```

and looking for "^M"

You can remove them by doing

```
tr -d '\r' < WindowsFile > UnixFile
```

or by using "dos2unix"

EDITED

From your comments, you appear to have two sets of adjacent double quotes at the end of the lines - is that correct? If so, you can replace two lots of quotes at the end of the line with a single set using this:

```
sed 's/""$/"/' YourFile > NewFile
```

Comment: Thanks @mark-setchell.  I ran the cat command and I do see this at the end of each line: ,"793930""^M$   I ran dos2unix on the file and now I see this at the end: ,"793930""$ Now if I run my same bash script to import, it does not import any records, I change the TERMINATED BY to '\n' and it imported but skips every other line.

Comment: Also, the first field of a skipped row is appended to the last field in the previous row, just as noted in my original post: 220  1243918  TGI  NA  AS-T5  M6 793930""220  The line break is being a booger!

Comment: You are exactly correct... there are two sets of quotation marks at the end of the line and by running the 'sed' command it fixed the issue!! Huge thanks!

Comment: Excellent! I love it when a plan comes together!

Comment: Thanks again! I was going nutz! And I didn't think of using dos2unix, although I use it on scripts that I download from Windows.. and the 'sed' command.. never even heard of that one!  Now that we got it working all the hard work can start now.. lol.